# MIssing Asp.Net Session ID Cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4, .Net4.5 application where we are using sessions.  For no apparent reason, MVC4 is not creating the Session ID Cookie.  Below is authentication and sessionstate settings from web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="480"></forms>
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="50" cookieless="UseCookies" mode="InProc"/>
```

It is not an issue with cookies as the Forms Auth cookie is present.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to get session cookie by JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For no apparent reason, MVC4 is not creating the Session ID Cookie.

Maybe you never stored anything in the session on the server:

```
Session["foo"] = "bar";
```

Only then you will see the session cookie being set to the response of this particular request. That's by design. Even if you enable ASP.NET Session on the server the cookie will never be set to the client until a value is stored in the session.

Comment: Then, How forms authentication will work without a session cookie? Sorry i am not sure about it. as my understanding is, it needs a ASP.Net session cookie

Comment: Forms Authentication and ASP.NET Sessions have absolutely nothing in common. Those are 2 completely different notions. For example you could perfectly fine use Forms Authentication and disable ASP.NET Session (my preferred scenario) or use ASP.NET Sessions without Forms Authentication. Many people confuse those 2 notions. Forms authentication provides a mechanism to track authenticated users on your site with cookies. ASP.NET Session provides you with a mechanism to store .NET objects on the server that could be retrieved in subsequent requests.

Comment: in webforms , there were situations where the sessionid was changed each request(if you hadn't restore something in the session) i believe the more appropriate way - is not setting the cookie at all - which is exactly what MVC 4 is doing :-)